# Solr: combining EdgeNGramFilterFactory and NGramFilterFactory

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I have a situation where I need to use both EdgeNGramFilterFactory and NGramFilterFactory.

I am using NGramFilterFactory to perform a "contains" style search with min number of characters as 2. I also want to search for the first letter, like a "startswith" with a front EdgeNGramFilterFactory.

I dont want to lower the NGramFilterFactory to min characters of 1 as I dont want to index all  characters.

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to do all this in the same field. I would create a different fields using different custom types for each treatment so that you can apply the logic separately.

In the following:

- `text` contains the original tokens, minimally processed;
- `text_ngram` uses the NGramFilter for your two-character-minimum tokens
- `text_first_letter` uses EdgeNGram for your one-character initial-letter tokens

If you're processing all `text` fields in this way, then you might be able to get away with using a `copyField` to populate the fields. Otherwise, you can instruct your Solr client to send in the same field values for the three separate field types.

When searching, include all of them in your searches with the `qf` parameter.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_first_letter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="1" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Setting up `field` and `dynamicField` definitions are left up to you. Or let me know if you have more questions and I can edit with clarifications.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although we would have liked it in the same field as there will be many situations where we will need it, but this will work!

Comment: @Nick Nadrozny, can you please let me know how to do this: "Otherwise, you can instruct your Solr client to send in the same field values for the three separate field types." and "When searching, include all of them in your searches with the qf parameter."? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Start by applying the EdgeNgramFilter with min = 1 and max = 1000 (we want the entire original token to be included). Example:

hello => 'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello'

Secondly use the NGramFilter with min = 2. (I will use 2 as the max in the example for simplicity)

'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello' => 'h', 'he', 'he', 'el', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'lo'

Now you will have several identical tokens since you have applied the NGramFilter on all "partial" tokens from the EdgeNGramFilter but simply apply the RemoveDuplicatesTokensFilter to remove those.

'h', 'he', 'he', 'el', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'lo' => 'h', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'lo'

Now your field will support a single char "startsWith" query and a multiple chars "contains" query.

Comment: This doesnt work because the contains NGram removes any single characters generated by the startswith EdgeNgram filter